# Codeginter 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a site that's up an running. It started life using index.php in the url. I've since stripped it out but in order not to duplicate content, I need to do a 301 redirect on any exisiting paths that may exist that still use index.php.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|public|)

# Prevent CI index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]


RewriteRule   ^register   /index.php/register/ [L]
```

That works nicely for domain.com/register

How can i also get it to 301 for domain.com/index.php/register, yet still retain just domain.com/register in the address bar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the very top (just under `RewriteEngine on`):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: almost there!! domain.com/index.php/register now rewrites in the address bar to domain.com//register. Any ideas how to remove the unwanted forward slash?? Thanks

Comment: @lunchboxbill yeah, change `index\.php([^\?\ ]*)` to `index\.php/([^\?\ ]*)`